# Can IntelliJ display a searchable maven dependency like Eclipse?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm starting to use IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate Edition and was wonder if it had a searchable tabular view of maven dependencies for a project like Eclipse does.
For example, in Eclipse I can check my project's maven dependencies by going to its pom and then clicking on the "Dependencies Hierarchy" tab. From there, I can search for the existence of specific dependencies and have the ability to view the POMs of said dependencies.

All I've found so far in IntelliJ is the diagram view of dependencies, which can get really cluttered when you have a lot of dependencies and doesn't really allow me to view POMs or search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, you have the maven plugin enabled, and you can build your project in IntelliJ via the `Maven Projects` pane (top right) ?

Now, you can see all your maven dependencies in a *linear* list in the `Project` pane (top left), underneath your source code. You can also type a search-string (e.g. "apache" will highlight all your `org.apache.x.y.z` dependencies.

For a **structural** view of the dependencies, you can start with one of the maven modules in the `Maven Projects` pane. Go to `My Module` -> `dependencies` and browse the tree. You can go to the pom of any of the dependencies in this tree with <kbd>f4</kbd>.

From within any pom, control-clicking on another artifactId will navigate to that pom, if available.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem with browsing from the Project tool window is that it won't divide dependencies per module, instead it shows ALL the dependencies for all of my sub-modules. And my problem in searching in the Maven Project tool window is that I'll have to expand the dependency tree for a sub module manually in order to see them all :\ I wish it was more robust than that and capable of showing conflicts. Even though it doesn't really match what I used to get from Eclipse, I'll still accept your answer since I guess this is as good as it gets on Intellij. Thanks again

Comment: No worries. You can always make a feature request on youtrack and, if it gets upvoted enough, it may eventually be implemented.

Comment: See Meo's answer, it matches the request more closely

Answer (score 68):

Try [Maven Helper plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce): once you install it, every POM file gets a tab for "Dependency Analyzer" which also includes a search bar.

If you need something more, report an issue. But it should be easy to implement it yourself and send a pull request.

Comment: once you install it, POM file gets a tab for "Dependency Analyzer" good one.

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Works like a charm.

Comment: Open root pom in editor -> Right-click context menu \ Run Maven \ New Goal... \ `dependency:tree -Dverbose`. This will analyze all nested poms at once.

Comment: Best answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, do you know a plugin like this for Gradle? Thanks!