# How to view maven dependency hierarchy in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I can see the dependency hierarchy in Eclipse.
How can I do it in IntelliJ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can IntelliJ display a searchable maven dependency like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001200/can-intellij-display-a-searchable-maven-dependency-like-eclipse)

Comment: mvn dependency:tree on the command-line ;)

Comment: Can this be done up to certain level?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can try:
Menu -> View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects

And then you can see new view openned.

Open your Dependencies tree, and you can see all the dependency hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: But we can't filter and search for a particular dependency. There the plugin "https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea_ce/plugin/7179-maven-helper" comes handy!

Answer (score 148):

I also like the [Maven Helper Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea_ce/plugin/7179-maven-helper).

Allows you to see dependencies as a tree, see conflicts, search in them. It looks a lot like the Eclipse tooling.

Notice the `Text` and `Dependency Analyzer` tabs that appear at the bottom of the POM editor panel. Click the analyzer tab to see results as shown in this screenshot.

[image: screenshot of Maven Helper Plugin window]

Comment: Not sure if this is new, but this functionality seems to be available in the built-in Maven Tool Window: https://imgur.com/NmvWcbJ

Comment: The plugin allows you to see where different versions come from which is quite useful when resolving the "dependency hell" of clashing transitive versions. I also like the searchable tree view a lot.

Comment: This is the best plugin to have if you are working in jar hell :) The tree view and the means to exclude transitive dependencies is a god send.

Comment: Does this plugin work with gradle as well? It would be magnificent in that case :)

Comment: This is the only answer that is suitable for large project with a lot dependencies, should be accepted. This help to find out conflicts quickly & easily, other answer can't do that !

Answer (score 65):

Offical documentation: [View Maven dependencies as a diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram)

Open the pom.xml, right click anywhere in the editor and choose "Diagrams > Show Dependencies".
It opens a dependency tree like those I'm attaching.

The main point is that this context menu appears only on opened pom.xml file (at least I couldn't managed to open it from anywhere else), if you just click on the file in the project tree, it won't be present.

**Please note:** You need to have [**UML Support**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram) and [**Maven Integration Extension**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_diagram)  enabled for this.

[image]

Comment: BTW, this is provided by the UML Support plug-in

Comment: You can open the diagram using a hot-key or by clicking a (well-hidden) icon; see my answer below /salute

Comment: I dont't think so, as this depends on the UML plugin which is included in Ultimate edition only.

Comment: My diagram has a bunch of blank boxes. If I mouse over them, I get the artifact id, but it's useless for a large project.

Comment: How is this better than the Maven Helper Plugin given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41546730/6648326 ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 That is simple. It is not.

Comment: That works for my project's pom file, but not for the effective-pom.xml though.

Comment: For large project with a lot dependencies, this simply doesn't work at all, you can see or navigate !!!

Answer (score 18):

Use the shortcut Luke! **`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U`**

Or select `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Maven Projects`

...here you can either:

A) expand the `Dependencies` sub-tree,

or

B) select the project ("spring-boot" in my case), **a new icon reveals itself**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Select Module or Directory and then Analyze from main menu

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Menu -> View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects is impractical and must be collapsed one by one. I prefer the plujin mentioned by Basil Bourque in this post.

Answer (score 2):

I love this plugin [Maven Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper), but for some reason it was crashing my IntelliJ:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.6948.69, built on August 25, 2020
```

I tried updating from the marketplace from within IntelliJ, but for some reason it didn't help.
I managed to solve this by installing it from the plugin website [Maven Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper) by clicking on "Install to IDE".

Comment: Here is the [plugin GitHub repo](https://github.com/krasa/MavenHelper) if you want to follow for updates or open issues.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @Ondrej Burkert the Maven Helper Plugin you can select the pom.xml file and if the editor is open there are two tabs at the bottom. First is 'Text' and second is 'Dependency Analyser'. In the tab 'Dependency Analyser' you have a tree of all dependencies like in eclipse.