# How to see which entry in pom.xml is responsible for an external dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependency-management

Lets say we have only 2 dependencies (namely `a` and `b`) in pom.xml, which installs 3 more dependencies ( `a`  installs -> `x` and `y`) and ( `b`  installs -> `z`).

When I go to `Analyze` -> `Analyze dependencies` in Intellij I see , a,b,x, y,z are listed under external dependencies but I dont see a way to figure out that `y` is actually installed by `a`.

Please show a screenshot , how to see that .[image]

Comment: possibly related: [How to view maven dependency hierarchy in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447650/how-to-view-maven-dependency-hierarchy-in-intellij)

Comment: Dependency Analyzer tab does not help?