# How to show maven dependencies in Ideal Intellij but up to certain tree level?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Related question: [How to view maven dependency hierarchy in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447650/how-to-view-maven-dependency-hierarchy-in-intellij)
[image]

I am using Intellij Digram of dependency, I can see the dependency tree but it shows all dependencies till the leaves of the tree, what If I want to see only root, level - 2, and probably level - 3 only? How to do that?
Or maybe there is a functionality to filter by group id?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with this?

Comment: When I use the draw, the tree it draws has all the dependencies, I only want to see how my modules are dependant on each other only I don't want to see all added library

Comment: There is no such an option. Please vote for the related request: [IDEA-87483](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87483/Add-filtering-of-non-top-level-project-dependencies-on-Show-Dependencies-Screen) Add filtering of non-top-level project dependencies on Show Dependencies Screen

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=your.groupid.*`.

This lists all dependencies which have (or start with) the same groupId.

Comment: Ok, but I want to visualize them in Intellij Idea Diagrams