# How to see dependency tree for JARS in IntelliJ using SBT

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

I am using intelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 for spark-scala using SBT.

i have many dependencies jars but i wanted to know that which jar is getting downloaded or coming along BECOZ of which jar.

For example i have specified Jar_1 in my build.sbt file. Now when the project is built using SBT, along with Jar_1, multiple jars like jar_1.1, jar_1.2, jar_1.3 also gets downloaded. Now when i click on  jar_1.3 or jar_1.2 i don't see the directory or any tree like structure which shows that its a child of Jar_1.

This feature is present in Eclipse. Attaching the image which shows this kind of Hierarchy.

[image: Dependency Hierarchy]

As you can see the jars and also it shows that because of which jars it was downloaded. I need to know that whether such thing is available in IntelliJ if yes how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can IntelliJ display a searchable maven dependency like Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001200/can-intellij-display-a-searchable-maven-dependency-like-eclipse)

Comment: Not a Duplicate. I am using SBT and not MAVEN

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in IntelliJ IDEA for the SBT based projects at the moment, please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11038).